не запускается терминал в Pycharm
при запуске терминала получаю ошибку, что данный процесс работает и предлагает завершить процесс или закончить...
в результате терминал не работает

пробовал cmd, WindowsPowerShell, bash
пути указывал правильно, плагин "терминал" подключен
